# How to avoid maven profile duplication

Tags: maven, dry

I have a maven project for a webapp, which repack war dependency using overlays. For two profiles, *test* and *prod*, it should exclude *demo.jsp* file, but for other, for example *local*, this file should stay. Is there a way to have only one configuration for two profiles? I don't want to repeat one configuration for two profiles. 
My current solution:

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>test</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <overlays>
                            <overlay>
                                <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
                                <artifactId>mywebapp</artifactId>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>demo.jsp</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </overlay>
                        </overlays>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <overlays>
                            <overlay>
                                <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
                                <artifactId>mywebapp</artifactId>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>demo.jsp</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </overlay>
                        </overlays>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

EDIT: *test* and *prod* profiles are identical

Comment: are there any differences between test and prod? They look similar in your snippet. Maybe you should check the feature toggle - http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FeatureToggle.html

Comment: @SpaceTrucker test and prod profiles are identical

Answer (score 0):

The [Plugin Management](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management) may help us as the following :-

```xml
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <overlays>
                    <overlay>
                        <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mywebapp</artifactId>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>demo.jsp</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </overlay>
                </overlays>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Then the `profiles` should be as the following: -

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>test</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
        ...
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
        ...
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

I hope this may help.

Comment: but then will have to define *local* profile to somehow override configuration from pluginManagement. *demo.jsp* should stay for *local* profile.

Comment: what if we define the excluded jsp as a properties, something like ${my.excluded.jsp}? And let each profile to define itself?

Comment: it would be good, but not ideal solution :-). Is there a way to have one profile configuration for two profiles with two different ids?